# Proof of Schur's Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, tensors

On Pg. 123 of Schaum's Tensor Calculus:

> At an isotropic point of **$R^n$** the Riemannian curvature is given by $$K=\frac{R_{abcd}}{g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc}}=\frac{R_{abcd}}{G_{abcd}}$$
>
> for any specific subscript string such that $G_{abcd}$ is nonzero.
>
> This formula can be proved by first constructing the fourth order tensor
>   $$T_{ijkl}=R_{ijkl}-KG_{ijkl}$$
>   and it must be proved that all $T_{ijkl}=0$ at an isotropic point $P$. Since $K$ is independent of direction at $P$, so are the $T_{ijkl}$; 
>   $$T_{ijkl}U^iV^jU^kV^l=0$$ $$(T_{ijkl}=T_{ijkl}(P))$$ 
>   (used the fact that $K=\frac{R_{ijkl}U^iV^jU^kV^l}{G_{pqrs}U^pV^qU^rU^s}$)
>
> Define the second-order tensor $$(S_{ik})=(T_{ijkl}V^jV^l)$$one can easily show that $S_{ik}=S_{ki}$

However, I have not been able to see how this symmetry property holds from the definition of $(S_{ik})$ (and doesn't this assume that $R_{ijkl}=R_{kjil}$? Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485353/proof-of-schurs-theorem